# how to convert JSONArray to List of Object using camel-jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

Am having the String of json array as follow

```
{"Compemployes":[
    {
        "id":1001,
        "name":"jhon"
        },
        {
                "id":1002,
        "name":"jhon"
        }
]}
```

i want to convert this this jsonarray to `List<Empolyee>` . for this i had added the the maven dependency "`camel-jackson`" and also write the pojo class for employee . but when i try to run my below code

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 List<Employe> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, TypeFactory.collectionType(List.class, Employe.class));
```

am getting the following exception.

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@43caa144; line: 1, column: 1]
```

can someone pls tell what am missing or doing anyting wrong

Comment: Its giving me exception if i tried to use dependency of "org.json".

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try to configure an object mapper like this:  mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The problem is not in your code but in your json:

```
{"Compemployes":[{"id":1001,"name":"jhon"}, {"id":1002,"name":"jhon"}]}
```

this represents an object which contains a property Compemployes which is a list of 
Employee. In that case you should create that object like:

```
class EmployeList{
    private List<Employe> compemployes;
    (with getter an setter)
}
```

and to deserialize the json simply do:

```
EmployeList employeList = mapper.readValue(jsonString,EmployeList.class);
```

If your json should directly represent a list of employees it should look like:

```
[{"id":1001,"name":"jhon"}, {"id":1002,"name":"jhon"}]
```

Last remark:

```
List<Employee> list2 = mapper.readValue(jsonString, 
TypeFactory.collectionType(List.class, Employee.class));
```

`TypeFactory.collectionType` is *deprecated* you should now use something like:

```
List<Employee> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString,
TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class,  
   Employee.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the client is sending data in the given format only, so is there any way to handle this automatically or need to handle it and manipulate the string to get in the format which you had told ?

Comment: updated my response: you should create an Object x with a List<Employe> compemployes property.

Comment: HI the approach works. but i had the json format coming as it shown above , so need to do some manipulation to it before further processing

Comment: or you can create an intermediate object EmployeList with member List<Employe> compemployes

Comment: Hmm, I sense there is more to be done in the "EmployeList" class than just add "some" getter and setter.. Doesn't really give the direction. Nothing is going to happen when you try to serialize to that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 It has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array/33292260#33292260
 * put string into file jsonFileArr.json
 * [{"username":"Hello","email":"hello@email.com","credits"
 * :"100","twitter_username":""},
 * {"username":"Goodbye","email":"goodbye@email.com"
 * ,"credits":"0","twitter_username":""},
 * {"username":"mlsilva","email":"mlsilva@email.com"
 * ,"credits":"524","twitter_username":""},
 * {"username":"fsouza","email":"fsouza@email.com"
 * ,"credits":"1052","twitter_username":""}]
 */

public class TestaGsonLista {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Gson gson = new Gson();
 try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "C:\\Temp\\jsonFileArr.json"));
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(br).getAsJsonArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
        JsonElement str = jsonArray.get(i);
        Usuario obj = gson.fromJson(str, Usuario.class);
        //use the add method from the list and returns it.
        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println("-------");
    }
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem with JSON output format. This code worked for me with the above JSON format.

```
package com.test.ameba;

import java.util.List;

public class OutputRanges {
    public List<Range> OutputRanges;
    public String Message;
    public String Entity;

    /**
     * @return the outputRanges
     */
    public List<Range> getOutputRanges() {
        return OutputRanges;
    }

    /**
     * @param outputRanges the outputRanges to set
     */
    public void setOutputRanges(List<Range> outputRanges) {
        OutputRanges = outputRanges;
    }

    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    /**
     * @param message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Message = message;
    }

    /**
     * @return the entity
     */
    public String getEntity() {
        return Entity;
    }

    /**
     * @param entity the entity to set
     */
    public void setEntity(String entity) {
        Entity = entity;
    }
}

package com.test;


public class Range {
    public String Name;
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Object[] Value;
    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public Object[] getValue() {
        return Value;
    }
    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(Object[] value) {
        Value = value;
    }

}

package com.test.ameba;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JSONTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String jsonString ="{\"OutputRanges\":[{\"Name\":\"ABF_MEDICAL_RELATIVITY\",\"Value\":[[1.3628407124839714]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_RX_RELATIVITY\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_Unique_ID_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_FIRST_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_AMEBA_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_Effective_Date_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_AMEBA_MODEL\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_UC_ER_COPAY_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_INN_OON_DED_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_COINSURANCE_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_PCP_SPEC_COPAY_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_INN_OON_OOP_MAX_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_IP_OP_COPAY_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_PHARMACY_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]},{\"Name\":\" ABF_PLAN_ADMIN_ERR\",\"Value\":[[\"CPD\",\"SL Limit\",\"Concat\",1,1.5,2,2.5,3]]}],\"Message\":\"\",\"Entity\":null}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        OutputRanges OutputRanges=null;
        try {
            OutputRanges = mapper.readValue(jsonString, OutputRanges.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("OutputRanges :: "+OutputRanges);;
        System.out.println("OutputRanges.getOutputRanges() :: "+OutputRanges.getOutputRanges());;
        for (Range r : OutputRanges.getOutputRanges()) {
            System.out.println(r.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

 String jsonText = readAll(inputofyourjsonstream);
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
 JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("Compemployes");
```

Your arr would looks like: [
    {
        "id":1001,
        "name":"jhon"
        },
        {
                "id":1002,
        "name":"jhon"
        }
]
You can use:

```
arr.getJSONObject(index)
```

to get the objects inside of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar json response coming from client. Created one main list class, and one POJO class.