# How to convert JSONArray to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-json

i have JSONArray(not JSONObject) , content of this array looks like :

```
[{"ID":"24","CardName":"Gool","CardCode":"9785898080617","CardCodeType":"EAN-13","CardHolderName":"\u041f\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0438\u043d","CardCountryCode":"UA","CardHolderID":"3","CardSumRait":"55","VotesCount":"11","Rating":"5"},{"ID":"25","CardName":"XCode","CardCode":"9785898080617","CardCodeType":"EAN-13","CardHolderName":"\u041f\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0438\u043d","CardCountryCode":"UA","CardHolderID":"3","CardSumRait":"31","VotesCount":"8","Rating":"3.875"}]
```

Now i need to convert it to ArrayList ,i was looking for different manuals , but and try some code:

My **JSONParcer**:

```
public class JSONParcer {

ArrayList<Person> getArrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Person>();
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jsonObject = null;
static String json = "";

//конструктор
public JSONParcer() {

}
class Person {
    public String cardID;
    public String cardName;
    public String cardCode;
    public String cardCodeType;
    public String cardHolderName;
    public String cardCountryCode;
    public String cardHolderID;
    public String cardSumRait;
    public String votesCount;
    public String rating;
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    //делаем HTTP запрос

    try {
        //default HTTP client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();




    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON parcer" , "Error parcing data " +e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Person resultRow = new Person();

            resultRow.cardID = json_data.getString("ID");
            resultRow.cardName = json_data.getString("CardName");
            resultRow.cardCode = json_data.getString("CardCode");
            resultRow.cardCodeType = json_data.getString("CardCodeType");
            resultRow.cardHolderName = json_data.getString("CardHolderName");
            resultRow.cardCountryCode =json_data.getString("CardCountryCode");
            resultRow.cardHolderID = json_data.getString("CardHolderID");
            resultRow.cardSumRait = json_data.getString("CardSumRait");
            resultRow.votesCount = json_data.getString("VotesCount");
            resultRow.rating = json_data.getString("Rating");


            getArrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

My **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


String jsonString;
Button btn;

ArrayList<Person> getArrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Person>();

public void showArrayinLogs(View view) {
    new JsonParce().execute();
}

class Person {
    public String cardID;
    public String cardName;
    public String cardCode;
    public String cardCodeType;
    public String cardHolderName;
    public String cardCountryCode;
    public String cardHolderID;
    public String cardSumRait;
    public String votesCount;
    public String rating;
}

String url1 = "/*my url here*/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class JsonParce extends AsyncTask<String , String, JSONObject>{

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParcer jsonParcer = new JSONParcer();
        JSONObject json = jsonParcer.getJSONFromUrl(url1);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject ) {
        int a = getArrayOfWebData.size();
        for(int i =0 ; i<a ; i++){
            Log.i("WORKS", getArrayOfWebData.get(i).toString());
        }

    }
}
```

}

When i start my program and click on button to show array in logs i have this

```
  Value [{"Rating":"5","CardName":"Gool","VotesCount":"11","CardSumRait":"55","CardHolderName":"Пупкин","ID":"24","CardCountryCode":"UA","CardHolderID":"3","CardCode":"9785898080617","CardCodeType":"EAN-13"},{"Rating":"3.875","CardName":"XCode","VotesCount":"8","CardSumRait":"31","CardHolderName":"Пупкин","ID":"25","CardCountryCode":"UA","CardHolderID":"3","CardCode":"9785898080617","CardCodeType":"EAN-13"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I understand that i make mistake in my **JSONParcer** class, but can u explain me what i need to change in it? Just rename JSONObject to JSONArray didnt work correctly. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `JSONParcer` class. In the code below, you are trying to create a JSON Object from a JSON Array (`json`) that's why you are getting the error `type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`.

```
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON parcer" , "Error parcing data " +e.toString());
}
```

A fix for this would be to remove that part of your code since you are reading `json` twice.

You are already doing it correctly here --> `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);`.

```
public class JSONParcer {

    ArrayList<Person> getArrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Person>();
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    static String json = "";

    ....


    // change getJSONFromUrl to return ArrayList<Person>
    public ArrayList<Person> getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    //делаем HTTP запрос

    ....


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try{
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Person resultRow = new Person();

            resultRow.cardID = json_data.getString("ID");
            resultRow.cardName = json_data.getString("CardName");
            resultRow.cardCode = json_data.getString("CardCode");
            resultRow.cardCodeType = json_data.getString("CardCodeType");
            resultRow.cardHolderName = json_data.getString("CardHolderName");
            resultRow.cardCountryCode =json_data.getString("CardCountryCode");
            resultRow.cardHolderID = json_data.getString("CardHolderID");
            resultRow.cardSumRait = json_data.getString("CardSumRait");
            resultRow.votesCount = json_data.getString("VotesCount");
            resultRow.rating = json_data.getString("Rating");

            getArrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return ArrayList<Person>
    return getArrayOfWebData;
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity`, change the object returned by `doInBackground`, the object input type to `AsyncTask` and the object input type to `onPostExecute` to `JSONArray`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

...

public class JsonParce extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Person>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Person> doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParcer jsonParcer = new JSONParcer();
        ArrayList<Person> personArrayList = jsonParcer.getJSONFromUrl(url1);
        return personArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Person> personArrayList) {
        int a = personArrayList.size();
        for(int i =0 ; i<a ; i++){
            Log.i("WORKS", personArrayList.get(i).toString());
        }

    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

I updated my answer, based on your comment. Your `JsonParce` `AsyncTask` now returns an `ArrayList` of `Person`s. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i tried your solution, and it nothng showed in logs , i didnt understand why its happend

Comment: nothing, i add button.setbtn.setEnabled false and true to see when the process ended , process end and nothing happend

Comment: may be it didnt show because my arraylist didnt create correctly?

Comment: i want to see in logs : "Works" id : 1 cardName :test  cardHolder:.. etc.;works id : 2 cardName: test2 ; cardHolder:... etc .. So i want to see full Array of Cards which i have on my server

Comment: have u any ideas why logs didnt show ? i call AsyncTask  in button click : new JsonParce().execute();

Comment: @Ololoking The logs are not showing because `getArrayOfWebData` is empty. You initialized it twice. You should initialize it just once and make your  `getJSONFromUrl` return it. Try putting the logs in your `getJSONFromUrl` method to confirm that it is not empty in there.

Comment: one more question, so how can i call my `getArrayOfWebData` from **JSONParcer class**  in **MainActivity** for example to get array.size?

Answer (score 0):

As json string is provided in post is `JSONArray of JSONObject` instead of JSONObject. so need to get JSONArray from response of api.

Make following change in `getJSONFromUrl` method:

**1.**  Change `getJSONFromUrl` method return type to `JSONArray` from `JSONObject`

**2.**  Convert response string to `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`:

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

**3.**  Return `jsonArray` from `getJSONFromUrl`

**4.** In `MainActivity` class get `JSONArray` from `getJSONFromUrl` method:

```
JSONArray json = jsonParcer.getJSONFromUrl(url1);
```

**5.** Also change `doInBackground` method return type to `JSONArray`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it like what you are using or you can do the same with more less code and more performance by using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson) or you can use [Jackson](http://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjackson.codehaus.org%2F&ei=9qDoVP79AdHgaIeOgbAB&usg=AFQjCNEVenmX5WpDaLAxyQRjqVpvRP8g_A&sig2=M11UIIO_8fB0qni7mVtyRw&bvm=bv.86475890,d.d2s) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271065/how-to-convert-jsonarray-to-list-of-object-using-camel-jackson).