# Unable to map API response to pojo

Tags: java, json, mapping, objectmapper, linkedhashmap

I have a json response

> "data": {
> "students": [
> {
> "id": 100,
> "name": "ABC"
> },
> {
> "id": 101,
> "name": "XYZ"
> }

I need to map it to my pojo, something like -

```
public class TempClass {

     List<Temp> list_students;

}

class Temp {
    Long id;
    String name;

}
```

Direct reading API response into my pojo gives me a class cast exception. I've tried converting response to a list of map and the collect as Temp class but that also doesn't work.

Exception -

> java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java object

Any suggestions please?

Code snippet for conversion -

```
new TempClass(((LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) response.getData()).entrySet())
                            .stream().map(map -> mapper.convertValue(map, Temp.class))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Comment: Also share the code of how you are converting the response into POJO.

Comment: Hey @SayanBhattacharya, updated. Please check.

Comment: You are not considering`data` and `students` key while converting . If you are trying to convert the whole response then your POJO should also have all the properties. Its unnecessary to cast it into  `HashMap`.  You can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271065/)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Data{
    public ArrayList<Student> students;
}

public class Root{
    public Data data;
}

public class Student{
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

Your **POJO** class will look like this