# data not displaying from database in android table layout

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-tablelayout

Hi In My Application I designed form if I click submit button I want to show the data in table format in android.

Now If I click the submit button it showing only field names data was not displaying.I was printed the output by using logcat it printing data.But logcat it's giving one error.

**Attend.class**

```
public class Attend extends Activity {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

        final DataseData getdb = new DataseData();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Users> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        try {           

JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(result);
             JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsnobject.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Users user = new Users();
                user.setClass_id(explrObject.getInt("class_id"));
                user.setClass_name(explrObject.getString("class_name"));
                user.setSection_name(explrObject.getString("section_name"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return users;
    }

    void addHeader(){

        tr = new TableRow(this);

        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("class_id");
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        label.setTextSize(15);

        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); 


        TextView class_name = new TextView(this);
        class_name.setText("class_name");
        class_name.setTextSize(15);

        class_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        class_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        class_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        class_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(class_name,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); 


        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tl.removeAllViewsInLayout();

        TextView section_name = new TextView(this);
        section_name.setText("section_name");
        section_name.setTextSize(15);

        section_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        section_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        section_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
section_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(section_name,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); 


        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Users p = (Users) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getClass_id());

            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);

            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll);


            TextView class_name = new TextView(this);
            class_name.setText(p.getClass_name());
            class_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            class_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(class_name,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); 


            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            TextView section_name = new TextView(this);
            section_name.setText("section_name");
            section_name.setTextSize(15);

            section_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            section_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            section_name.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
    section_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll.addView(section_name,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); 


            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php
$username ='root';
$password ='';
$hostname ='localhost';
$database ='login';

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database,$localhost);
$i=mysql_query("select class_id,class_name,section_name from class");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($i);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($i))
{

$r[]=$row;
$check=$row['id'];            }

if($check==NULL)
{
$r[$num_rows]="Record is not available";
print(json_encode($r));
}
else
{
$r[$num_rows]="success";
print(json_encode($r));
}

mysql_close($localhost);
?>
```

**Logcat**

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"2":"Batch A","1":"Play Group","class_id":"101","0":"101","class_name":"Play Group","section_name":"Batch A"},{"2":"Batch B","1":"Nursery","class_id":"102","0":"102","class_name":"Nursery","section_name":"Batch B"},{"2":"","1":"LKG","class_id":"103","0":"103","class_name":"LKG","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"Ukg","class_id":"104","0":"104","class_name":"Ukg","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"I st","class_id":"105","0":"105","class_name":"I st","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"II","class_id":"106","0":"106","class_name":"II","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"III","class_id":"107","0":"107","class_name":"III","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"IV","class_id":"108","0":"108","class_name":"IV","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"V","class_id":"109","0":"109","class_name":"V","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"VI","class_id":"110","0":"110","class_name":"VI","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"VII","class_id":"121","0":"121","class_name":"VII","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"VIII","class_id":"122","0":"122","class_name":"VIII","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"IX","class_id":"123","0":"123","class_name":"IX","section_name":""},{"2":"","1":"X","class_id":"124","0":"124","class_name":"X","section_name":""},"success"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should convert your string to **JSONObject** and then you can get **JSONArray** from your **JSONObject** with using a key word. The [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array) is about this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: `JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray(result);` is wrong. **result** must be a key for your related JSONArray. Or really you have JSONArray?

Comment: what name I have to use in my php

Comment: [{"2":"Batch A","1":"Play Group","class_id":"101","0":"101","class_name":"Play Group","section_name":"Batch A"},{"2":"Batch B","1":"Nursery","class_id":"102","0":"102","class_name":"Nursery","section_name":"Batch B"},success"]

Comment: can you please help me new to android

Comment: In My Code there is no array name

Comment: then add keys to arrays on your php service.