# Assertion of multiple key/value pairs

Tags: java, tdd, junit4

I am trying to write assertions to test the iteration of JSON array of objects.

I want to return each key value and use it elsewhere in my application.

For example:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
   jsonStringSingleObject  = "[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"A green door\", \"price\": \"12.50\"}]";

  jsonStringMultipleObjects  = "[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"A green door\", \"price\": \"12.50\"}, "
          + "{\"id\": 7, \"name\": \"Tesla\", \"price\": \"94.71\"}]";
}
```

Which I can then use the following test to check the id key:
I am iterating using the good old way as I do not have millions of data to iterate(up 100 max).

```
@Test 
public String idExtractor_checksSingleIDValueWhenPassedAnArrayWithIDKey() 
    throws JSONException {

    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonStringSingle);
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject objects = json.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = objects.getString("id");
        assertTrue(id.equals("1"));
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}
```

The test passes with a single object however, when I pass the `jsonStringMultipleObject`,
The test fails.
I managed to pass the test using

```
assertThat(id, anyOf(containsString("1"), containsString("2")));
```

But this does not resolve the underlying problem.
I would like to check the id per object and return it - something like

```
AssertTrue(id.equals("1")); ///test passes
```

Then check the second object

```
AssertTrue(id.equals("2")); ///test passes
```

TESTS PASSED!

if the first assertion fails, I need the whole test to fail.
Would this be possible?

Comment: Only if the first assertion fails, or if any assertion fails?

Comment: @Seth Any assertion fails because of the second object.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto it does not fail because of 7 or 1. The second object does not need to be 1. I am not comparing the objects. I Just want to individually check them to make sure id is what I expect it to be and return them

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question was if you want the test to fail *only if **the first assertion** fails, or if any assertion at all fails.*

Comment: @Seth Any assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Could your problem be related to using string construction to JSONArray directly?  See this question/answer:  [Convert string to JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array)