# Android JSON Parsing Throws Unexpected Exception

Tags: android, arrays, json

### Source:

```
try {
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(intent.getStringExtra("chatData"));

  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    messagesArr = new JSONArray(item.getString("message"));
    messagesObj = new JSONObject();
    messagesObj.put("messages", messagesArr);
    populateMessages(messagesObj);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

I've also attempted changing the following line with no success:

```
messagesArr = new JSONArray(item.getJSONObject("message"));
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Values:

```
item =  {"message":"User has joined.","type":"agent","created":"2016-11-21 20:55:22","name":"Username"}
```

### LogCat:

```
1-21 21:15:40.775 23532-23532/com.example.examplemobile W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Johnny of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
11-21 21:15:40.775 23532-23532/com.example.examplemobile W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
11-21 21:15:40.785 23532-23532/com.example.examplemobile W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
11-21 21:15:40.785 23532-23532/com.example.examplemobile W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
```

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Your JSON has no array, it looks like JSONObject

Comment: Note - when changing to messagesArr = new JSONObject(item.getString("message")); I get the following error: 

org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What does logging intent.getStringExtra("chatData") print out? Are you sure that your Intent.putExtra() is putting in valid JSON?

Comment: +1 @iNan.  @droidthusiast: Your logcat says `Value Johnny of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`, it means that either you get the wrong json data or you read the json data string as array .

Comment: TAG: [{"type":"agent","message":"User has joined the chat.","created":"2016-11-21 21:40:31","name":"User"},{"type":"agent","message":"example message,"created":"2016-11-21 21:40:36","name":"User"},{"type":"agent","message":"User has left the chat.","created":null,"name":"User"}]


(apologies - I was swapping out the actual users name with something generic after the fact)

Comment: I'm trying to read it as JSON Object instead of an array but I'm still getting errors (I apologize if I'm overlooking something obvious - it's getting late) 

http://pastebin.com/B0pQ34F2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse a `String` as a `JSONArray`, that's why it's throwing the exception. In order to parse it as a JSONArray, you'd have to have data like this: `{ "message":["String1", "String2", "String3"] }`

Change your `messagesArr` variable to a String, and then access the "message" string by calling `messagesArr = item.getString("message");`

Answer (score 1):

From your json string that you provided on your comment, it is not a valid json string

```
[{"type":"agent","message":"User has joined the chat.","created":"2016-11-21 21:40:31","name":"User"},{"type":"agent","message":"example message,"created":"2016-11-21 21:40:36","name":"User"},{"type":"agent","message":"User has left the chat.","created":null,"name":"User"}]
```

It needs a double quotation mark after `example message`

Try to change the json string to

```
[
  {
    "type": "agent",
    "message": "User has joined the chat.",
    "created": "2016-11-21 21:40:31",
    "name": "User"
  },
  {
    "type": "agent",
    "message": "example message",
    "created": "2016-11-2121: 40: 36",
    "name": "User"
  },
  {
    "type": "agent",
    "message": "Userhasleftthechat.",
    "created": null,
    "name": "User"
  }
]
```

and let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert your String JSON `intent.getStringExtra("chatData")`to JSON Array.

Maybe this link can help 
[Convert String To JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array)