# How to split a JSON message and convert it to a Singleton class

Tags: android, class, singleton

I'm new using this especial classes.
My problem is:

I recieve in a variable this JSON message:

```
String buffer = stringBuilder.toString();
```

String Buffer is this information. It has a list of empresas (Bussiness) and one parameter is a List of Proyects(that has two variables: money and information).

```
[
    {
        "name": "LOL",
        "address": "LCS",
        "phonenumber": 98987845,
        "email": "david@gmail.com",
        "creditcard": "7674774",
        "proyects": [
            {
                "money": 30000,
                "information": "This is my proyect",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "money": 0,
                "information": "My second proyect",
                "id": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "UPC",
        "address": "Castelldefels",
        "phonenumber": 93245098,
        "email": "aasasaasa@gmail.com",
        "creditcard": "asdfg9876",
        "proyects": [],
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

So then i create 3 java.class:
For example the class User is the following:

```
package com.example.david.dhl;
import java.util.List;

class User {

    static String name;
    static String password;
    static List<Empresa> Empresas;

    private static final Usuario ourInstance = new Usuario();

    static Usuario getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    private User() {

    }
}
```

How can i save all the information in the different singleton classes?
When i do this:

```
String a = User.getInstance().name;
```

It said that is empty.

Thank you very much.

PD: if any moderator can put the code more visual will be so nice, because i'm new and i don't find anything. Thank you.

Comment: because the name is empty,  put the class when you parse the json data

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: I will try. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array)

What you have to do is convert the string into a json array and then with a for loop iterate and the logic in each iteration.

Comment: I get lost in the loop

Comment: in each iteration of the for loop, do the logic you want.