# Write Java string array to JSON array using Jackson JSON Generator

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I want to write java string array into JSON array.

```
Array : ["abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno"]
```

One way is to loop over the array and add the elements one by one as below

```
JsonGenerator jsonGen = factory.createGenerator(output, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
jsonGen.writeArrayFieldStart("args");
for (String val : arr)  {
  jsonGen.writeString(val);
}
jsonGen.writeEndArray();
```

Is there any way to convert a string array into JSON array directly (i.e. without iterating over it)?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array

Comment: `objectMapper.writeValue(out, arr)`