# Get size of json from MvcResult

Tags: java, json, spring, mockmvc

I'm testing an API and get all data from the DB. I save the response as

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(..some code..).andReturn();
```

I get a json as response. I want to get the length of json array. 
So, if I have 2 rows in DB, I want to get 2 as a result.

Or is there maybe another way to count number of rows which are present in the DB.

Comment: Usually response of multiple rows will be an array, like `[ {row1},{row2},.., ]`. So you can `simply use array.length` property.

Comment: @Narendhran, I have an array, but I don't see in MvcResult  methods to convert in to array or to get length array length...

Comment: there are lot of third party library out there to convert json string to object, some of the famous libraries are Jackson, GSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get json array length this is the way,

1.if you import `org.json.simple.JSONArray` you can use `JSONArray.size()`

2.if you import `org.json.JSONArray` you can use `JSONArray.length()`

Comment: Why not use the built-in support for jsonpath instead of adding a new dependency?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using MockMvc instead of returning with `andReturn()` you can use the JSONPath support like:

```
  mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
  .get("/resource")
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.length").value(2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say your response is something like this:

```
{
  result : [
     {
       "field1": "a",
       "field2": "b"
     },
     {
       "field1": "c",
       "field2": "d"
     }
  ]
}
```

In this case you'd use MockMvc to write assertions like this:

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
.get("/resource")
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.result.length()").value(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **com.jayway.JsonPath** (you already have this class through spring-boot-starter-test )

```
Integer length = JsonPath.read(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), "$.length()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

and then try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array)