# (closed) Convert string list to Json Array

Tags: php, json, list

I have a string format like this:

> "Android Development : 1, Android Studio : 1, Kotlin : 1, Java : 1, Model-View-Presenter (MVP) : 0, "

I need to convert it to JSON format which looks like this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': "Android Development"}, {'id': 2, 'name': "Android Studio"},{'id': 3, 'name': "Kotlin"}, {'id': 4, 'name': "Java"}, {'id': 5, 'name': "Model-View-Presenter (MVP)"}]
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you want to do anything with the numeric values in the string?

Comment: Have a look on this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array

Comment: @SajibTalukder: the article you provide tried to parse a structured JSON string to java's object while OP wants to restructure a string to JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try code:

```
$str = "Android Development : 1, Android Studio : 1, Kotlin : 1, Java : 1, Model-View-Presenter (MVP) : 0,";
$arr1 = explode(",",$str);
$result = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    $arr2 = explode(":",$value);
    if(count($arr2)>0)
    {
        $result[] = $arr2[0];
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @NasruriAji if this answer help you then you should mark as 'Answer Accepted'.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string with `,` then save the content before `:` as name.

```
$result = [];
$string = "Android Development : 1, Android Studio : 1, Kotlin : 1, Java : 1, Model-View-Presenter (MVP) : 0, ";
$array = explode(',',$string);
$id = 1;
foreach($array as $str){
    if($pos = strpos($str,":")){
        $result[] = array(
            'id' => $id++,
            'name' => trim(substr($str,0,$pos))
        );
    }
}
print_r(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: This doesn't give JSON result. You must use `json_encode` to your `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$string = "Android Development : 1, Android Studio : 1, Kotlin : 1, Java : 1, Model-View-Presenter (MVP) : 0, ";

$array1 = explode(',', $string);
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
     $value = trim($value);
     if (!empty($value)) {
          $array2 = explode(':', $value);
          $result[$key]['id'] = $key;
          $result[$key]['name'] = $array2[0];
      }
 }

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string="Android Development : 1, Android Studio : 1, Kotlin : 1, Java : 1, Model-View-Presenter (MVP) : 0, ";
    $arr= preg_split( '/(,|:)/', $string);
    $output=[];
    for($i=0;$i<count($arr)-1;$i+=2)
        $output[]=[
        'name'=>$arr[$i],
        'id'=>(int)$arr[$i+1],
        ];

        echo json_encode($output);
```