# How to read the Json file for specific value in Java using Simple.json library

Tags: java, json

This what my Json file looks like.

```
[
   [
    "Name"
    "Age"
    "Height"
   ]
   [
    "Name"
    "Age"
    "Height"
   ]
]
```

How can I read the specific value like "Name" using simple.json in Java?

Comment: This is not json. Do you really mean your data is in arrays?

Comment: the file is stored as a .json file

Comment: well, but what showed us does not match json syntax.

Comment: yeah I understand that. Any way to read this specific value?

Comment: Also, which library are you referring to - I did not finr anything named `Simple.json`? Did you mean [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)?

Comment: You understand that this is not json, but still ask us how to parse it with a json parser? I'm somewhat... confused. Please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid json format. But anyway to read json data from a file you can open it and read it to string as shown in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/)

Then using org.json library you can parse string to either json array or object.

```
String fileDataJsonObject = "{"Name":"SomeName"}"; //string containing a json object
String fileDataJsonArray = "[{"Name":"SomeName"},{"Name":"SomeName2"}]"; //string containing a json array
 
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(fileDataJsonObject);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(fileDataJsonArray);
```

This is just an example of how you can parse string to json array or an object. For arrays you can then use `getJSONObject(index)` method to get json objects from array. Also you can use json object getters to get any element within that object.

p.s I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array) useful discussion on stackoverflow. The answers have different ways of parsing json object or array using different libraries.